# JRE failed even after open jdk as well as oracle

Tags: openjdk

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   
Status
------------------------------------------------------------

* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      

auto mode

 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      

manual mode

2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1         

manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1


$ java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

But when i try to install my bin tool:

```
$ ./DS41Client.bin 

          Initializing InstallShield Wizard........

          Extracting Bundled JRE.          


                    Bundled JRE is not binary compatible with host OS/Arch or 

it is corrupt.  Testing bundled JRE failed.
```

Can you please tell whats missing?

Comment: This site is about ubuntu. Questions about Arch should be asked in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you open the file in an editor?

Comment: Can't open the .bin file in editor... its about 300MB, editor will crash

Comment: Here's one. try disabling java from your machine and then re run that script and see what it says.. you can share the results

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 lts    Linux Inspiron-7548 3.16.0-37-generic #51~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 6 15:23:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It seems you have downloaded a version of some software with a bundled java installer that is for the wrong OS / Architecture.  You should check if there exists another installer that is specific for Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit - or at least 64 bit.

Comment: Last try: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`. Give me a comment with @A.B.

Comment: or try `wget` for the download.

Comment: @A.B.    : tried both dpkg and wget options, still not working, i had this thing working in my previous machine with same version of ubuntu and it never showed  any error like this.                                IS it possible there is some error in my ubuntu installation?   I am using dual boot with win8.1

Comment: Try this version. Maybe it works:http://download.accelrys.com/freeware/ds_visualizer/DS45/DS45Client.bin

Comment: @A.B. - No buddy still no luck, with DS45 also, Bundled JRE is not binary compatible with host OS/Arch or it is corrupt.  Testing bundled JRE failed       . Thanks Anyway for so much help.   What do you think where the problem is :  with package or my machine?

Comment: @ A.B. : i just run the DS45 you provided on another machine and its through                                                                                                                       Initializing InstallShield Wizard........
          Launching InstallShield Wizard........                  with just license error   Failed to load the module 'ls_license64_g411': libls_license64_g411.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.                                                I think there is something missing in my laptop which is causing this problem